# AJAX Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, post

I have received the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

For this line:

```
data: userCoupon: $('#couponCode').val(),
```

Below is the script:

```
$(function() {
  $("#signInButton2").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'coursePayment.php',
      data: userCoupon: $('#couponCode').val(),
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
    });    
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing object brackets so your line should be

`data: {userCoupon: $('#couponCode').val()},`

In the script:

```
$(function() {
    $("#signInButton2").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'coursePayment.php',
            data: {userCoupon: $('#couponCode').val()},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: For reference, see jQuery's `ajax()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [examples](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples) regarding how to specify a data *object*.

Comment: thanks. that error was correct. one another note, my success seems to be incorrect where i do not want an alert to appear rather just the value to be posted on the other page

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand. If you just want the `POST` request to happen without an alert, you could just remove the alert line.  The request will happen with or without a callback function.

Comment: i remove that line but it does not seem to post this is the input   <input type="text" oninput="calculate()" name="couponCode"  id="couponCode"  value="" placeholder="Please Enter Coupon Code" required>

Comment: Is the function being called when you click `#signInButton2`?  Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: yes it responds to signinbutton2 but this submit button is inside another form, while this input value being called is independant of any form

Comment: You're using jQuery to post which does not depend on the use of forms.

Comment: $coupon = $_POST['userCoupon'];
everything seems to be correct. whats happening here is that once the user succesfully login he is taken to coursePayment.php?crs_id=$crs_id

Comment: Please make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and post all the relevant code if you need more help.  It's difficult to figure out what the problem is based on short snippets.  If it is a different problem than the one originally asked, consider making a new question (posting relevant code) and tag appropriately (i.e. PHP)